# Multiple XkbOptions in xorg.conf

Tags: xorg, xkb

How should I write multiple XkbOptions in xorg.conf? I've tried "option,option,option", "option, option, option", "option option option" and none of these worked - only the first option was executed.

Answer (score 2):

As a very late answer to this question, applicable on 2017-era Xorg (`localectl` is part of `systemd`, but the xorg.conf format should apply to non-systemd configurations).  These options go in an `InputClass` section of `xorg.conf`.  My system uses `localectl` to set the options:

```
$ sudo localectl set-x11-keymap  us pc105 altgr-intl caps:hyper,compose:menu
#    format:               [layout] [model] [variant] [options]
```

This command creates a file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` with the specified options:

```
# Read and parsed by systemd-localed. It's probably wise not to edit this file
# manually too freely.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us"
        Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
        Option "XkbVariant" "altgr-intl"
        Option "XkbOptions" "caps:hyper,compose:menu"
EndSection
```

As you can see, both the `localectl` and `xorg.conf` specify the options in a comma-separated format (`option1,option2,...,optionN`).  If you're still having trouble, make sure any cached keymaps are removed from `/var/x11/xkb/`, and make sure you're specifying the correct option.  `localectl list-x11-keymap-options` will get you a list, or you can check in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`.